# Remove duplicates with a different equality test in Python

Tags: python, haskell, duplicates

I'm looking for a Python function similar to [`nubBy` in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3anubBy), which removes duplicate but with a different equality test.

The function would take the equality test and the list as parameters, and would return the list of elements with no duplicates.

**Example**:

```
In [1]: remove(lambda x, y: x+y == 12, [2, 3, 6, 9, 10])
Out[1]: [2,3,6]
```

For example, here (2 and 10) and (9 and 3) are duplicates. I don't care if the output is `[10, 9, 6]` or `[2, 3, 6]`.

Is there an equivalent built-in function in Python? If not, what is the best way to efficiently implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method (as the use case is rather esoteric), but you can easily write one:

```
def removeDups(duptest, iterable):
  res = []
  for e in iterable:
    if not any(duptest(e, r) for r in res):
       res.append(e)
  return res
```

Now, in the console:

```
>>> removeDups(lambda x,y: x+y == 10, [2,3,5,7,8])
[2, 3, 5]
>>> removeDups(lambda x,y: x+y == 10, [2,3,6,7,8])
[2, 3, 6]
>>> removeDups(lambda x, y: x+y == 12, [2, 3, 6, 9, 10])
[2, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

This `remove` function will allow you to specify any pairwise equality function. It will keep the last of each set of duplicates.

```
values = [2,3,5,7,8]

def addstoten(item, other):
    return item + other == 10

def remove(eq, values):
    values = tuple(values)
    for index, item in enumerate(values):
        if not any(eq(item, other) for other in values[index + 1:]):
            yield item

print list(remove(addstoten, values))
```

Comment: I think the last line should be `print (list(remove(...)))`. Also, this sadly doesn't work on iterables, just on lists.

Comment: @phihag He said `take the equality test and the list as parameters` but it can easily work on iterables as well if you don't mind `tuple`ing them.