# Filter unique pair from list of tuples in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unique

I have a list of tuples like [(A,B),(B,A),(D,C),(E,F),(C,D),(F,E)]. I want result as [(A,B),(C,D),(E,F)]?

Example:

```
[('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'), ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'), ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110'),('157.240.16.35', '1.1.1.10'),('140.205.94.193', '1.1.1.10')]
```

Expected result:

```
[('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'),('1.1.1.10', '157.240.25.35'),('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110'),]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicates with a different equality test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302378/remove-duplicates-with-a-different-equality-test-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

This makes a list where there are no duplicate permutations of `x`

```
a = [('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'),
     ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'),
     ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110'),
     ('157.240.16.35', '1.1.1.10'),
     ('140.205.94.193', '1.1.1.10')]


def clean(x):
    heap = []
    for i in x:
        if (i[0], i[1]) not in heap and (i[1], i[0]) not in heap:
            heap.append(i)
    return heap
```

```
>>> clean(a)
[('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'),
 ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'),
 ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110')]
```

Comment: This answer is more like sorting. This will not remove duplicates.

Comment: Freddy, I did the same logic. Pls refer in Rodrigo comment section.

Comment: What's wrong with this method?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Im just saying, even i also found similar logic.

Comment: Would you like me to do it in a different way? why did you refer me to your comment in Rodrigo's comments?

Comment: No offense here. I was proposing, similar logic was written now, so If you can provide different way, please share that as well.

Comment: Yeah thats all good man :) these types of questions are encouraged. Just make sure you give an example of what you have tried in the question, and that you are looking for alternative examples

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize set() and sorted() to eliminate duplicated tuple in any order.

```
raw =[
    ('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'), 
    ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'), 
    ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110'),
    ('157.240.16.35', '1.1.1.10'),
    ('140.205.94.193', '1.1.1.10')
]

print(list(set([tuple(sorted(r)) for r in raw])))
```

Result:

```
[('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'), ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'), ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an array of tuples? I believe you could create another array such that arr2[1] = arr[1]. arr[5] = arr2[2]. arr[6] = arr2[3].

That is if you always have the same size list, since it is very small. This may be the shortest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is some witchery that does the job.

(This is a little cryptic, so if I was you, I would do something more explicit, like the options available here: [Remove duplicates with a different equality test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302378/remove-duplicates-with-a-different-equality-test-in-python))

```
data =  [('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'), ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'), ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110'),('157.240.16.35', '1.1.1.10'),('140.205.94.193', '1.1.1.10')]

res = [(a, b) for a, b in reversed(data) if data.pop() and (a, b) not in data and (b, a) not in data]
```

Comment: I have tried similar method.>>> b=[]
>>> for x,y in data:
...   if (x,y) not in b and (y,x) not in b:
...      b.append((x,y))
...
>>> b
[('1.1.1.10', '140.205.94.193'), ('1.1.1.10', '157.240.16.35'), ('1.1.1.10', '172.217.163.110')]
>>>

Comment: removed the walrus now